# Python: How to generate a random array only consisting of a specific number of -1, 0, 1?

Tags: python, arrays, random

Is there a standard way in Python to generate an array (of size 15), where precisely three 1s and four -1s are placed randomly and the remaining array entries are 0?

An example for such an array would be

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 -1 1 -1 -1 0 0 0 -1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```py
from random import sample
array = sample([1, -1, 0], 15, counts=[3, 4, 8])
print(array)
```

Note that `counts` argument requires Python 3.9.

Using [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```py
from random import shuffle
array = 3 * [1] + 4 * [-1] + 8 * [0]
shuffle(array)
print(array)
```

Example output:

```
[0, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using Python 3.9, you could still do it with the sample function:

```
import random

size  = 15
ones  = 3
negs  = 4
zeros = size-ones-negs

result = random.sample([1]*ones + [-1]*negs + [0]*zeros, size)

print(result)
[1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0]
```